# Select Maximum Count From Group Of Events

Tags: sql, oracle, greatest-n-per-group

The SQL script

```
select eventid_nbr, trunc(received_date, 'DD'), sentindicator, count(eventid_nbr) as count
from eventlog
where received_date between to_date('2017-07-01, 10:00 A.M.','YYYY-MM-DD, HH:MI A.M.') and to_date('2017-07-01, 11:00 A.M.','YYYY-MM-DD, HH:MI A.M.')
group by eventid_nbr, trunc(received_date, 'DD'), sentindicator
order by count desc, trunc(received_date, 'DD');
```

has output

```
EVENT  RECEIVED_DATE  SENTINDICATOR   COUNT

1      01-JUL-17      Y               128
1      01-JUL-17      E1              2
104    01-JUL-17      Y               55
105    01-JUL-17      Y               4
106    01-JUL-17      Y               3
```

whereby I need the maximum count chosen amongst each event whereby the output would appear as

```
 EVENT  RECEIVED_DATE  SENTINDICATOR   COUNT

 1      01-JUL-17      Y           128
 104    01-JUL-17      Y           55
 105    01-JUL-17      Y           4
 106    01-JUL-17      Y           3
```

For each grouping, would I need to select max(count)?  How could I achieve this?

Comment: I've updated the question indicating I need to select all events (possibly 200) containing duplicates as above with event 1, and include only that tuple whose column COUNT is a MAX(COUNT). For non-duplicated events, such as 104, 105, and 106, their tuples are included in the result set whereby their counts are already a MAX(COUNT)

Answer (score 0):

In Oracle 12c, you can do:

```
select eventid_nbr, trunc(received_date, 'DD'), sentindicator, 
       count(eventid_nbr) as count
from eventlog
where received_date between to_date('2017-07-01, 10:00 A.M.','YYYY-MM-DD, HH:MI A.M.') and
                            to_date('2017-07-01, 11:00 A.M.','YYYY-MM-DD, HH:MI A.M.')
group by eventid_nbr, trunc(received_date, 'DD'), sentindicator
order by count desc, trunc(received_date, 'DD')
fetch first 1 row only;
```

In earlier versions, a subquery does the same thing:

```
select el.*
from (select eventid_nbr, trunc(received_date, 'DD'), sentindicator, 
             count(eventid_nbr) as count
      from eventlog
      where received_date between to_date('2017-07-01, 10:00 A.M.','YYYY-MM-DD, HH:MI A.M.') and
                                  to_date('2017-07-01, 11:00 A.M.','YYYY-MM-DD, HH:MI A.M.')
      group by eventid_nbr, trunc(received_date, 'DD'), sentindicator
      order by count desc, trunc(received_date, 'DD')
     ) el
where rownum = 1;
```

Comment: Can you please elaborate more based upon an edit to the question to bring further clarification?

Answer (score 0):

```
select eventid,dt,sentindicator,max(count)
from 
 (
  select eventid_nbr, trunc(received_date, 'DD') as dt, sentindicator, 
  count(eventid_nbr) as count
  from eventlog
  where received_date between to_date('2017-07-01, 10:00 A.M.','YYYY-MM-DD, 
  HH:MI A.M.') 
  and to_date('2017-07-01, 11:00 A.M.','YYYY-MM-DD, HH:MI A.M.'
  )
    group by eventid_nbr, trunc(received_date, 'DD'), sentindicator
    order by count desc, trunc(received_date, 'DD'))a
group by eventid,dt,sentindicator
```

Comment: just add an outer query with a max(count) as an outer query to your query

Answer (score 0):

```
select eventid_nbr, received_day, max(sentindicator) keep(dense_rank last order by count), max(count) as count
from (select eventid_nbr, trunc(received_date, 'DD') as received_day,  sentindicator, count(*) as count
        from eventlog
       where received_date between to_date('2017-07-01, 10:00 A.M.','YYYY-MM-DD, HH:MI A.M.') and to_date('2017-07-01, 11:00 A.M.','YYYY-MM-DD, HH:MI A.M.')
       group by eventid_nbr, trunc(received_date, 'DD'), sentindicator)
group by eventid_nbr, received_day
order by 4 desc, received_day;
```